# RXNORM to SNOMED mapping

Tags: medical, snomed-ct

We have medications listed in our medical system. They are mapped to [RxNorm](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/rxnorm/) ids.

We want to migrate to [Snomed](http://www.snomed.org/snomed-ct). 
Is there a way to match RxNorm ids to Snomed concept ids? Perhaps there is a database with links? Or a service?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SNOMED and RXNORM are very different in how they represent drug information. RXNORM is much more complete and encodes strength, administration route, packaging information and product names. SNOMED has mainly principal active ingredients and some product names. The coverage in SNOMED for strength and administration route is not great.

For instance SNOMED does not have IDs for `Prozac` but does have for `Fluoxetine` which is the principal ingredient of `Prozac`

In RXNORM you can find the following connections:

```
[PROzac Weekly 90 MG Delayed Release Oral Capsule]
-- ingredient --> [Prozac] 
-- precise ingredient --> [Fluoxetine]
```

And the ingredient concept will take you to SNOMED:

`[Fluoxetine]` `-->` `SNOMEDCT_US:53640004` `SNOMEDCT_US:372767007`

Bear in mind that most ingredient in SNOMED are duplicated as product and substance and each of these types give different relations.

Three options to implement this:

1. Use the RXNORM/NIH NLM data files https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/rxnorm/docs/rxnormfiles.html
2. BioPortal API (free) http://bioportal.bioontology.org/
3. Lexigram API (commercial) http://www.lexigram.io/

The important aspect here is that if you replace RXNORM IDs with SNOMED IDs you will be losing information but of course depending on your use case that might be just fine. I would consider using [NDCs](https://www.fda.gov/drugs/informationondrugs/ucm142438.htm).

Disclaimer: I was an engineer at BioPortal and currently CTO at Lexigram.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thanks to your response we decided to stay with RxNorm :)

Comment: The local extensions include addition trade names for medications.
https://termbrowser.nhs.uk/?perspective=full&conceptId1=9330601000001108&edition=uk-edition&release=v20180711&server=https://termbrowser.dataproducts.nhs.uk/sct-browser-api/snomed&langRefset=999001261000000100,999000691000001104

Comment: This is an old one now. But worth noting the UK use dm+d which is essentially a reserved chunk of extended SNOMED CT UK ID numbers. https://www.nhsbsa.nhs.uk/pharmacies-gp-practices-and-appliance-contractors/dictionary-medicines-and-devices-dmd